# android black color at 85% opacity

Tags: android, colors

What is the color code of black with 85% opacity?

I have #65000000 - but its too light. I need it a bit darker, at 85% opacity. How do I get that?

And why can't I setAlpha(85) on a relative layout? That's what I would want to do normally. But because this is not available, I have to do it though background color.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Each component goes from 0 through 255, so 85% opacity would be 85% of 255, i.e. 216.

So: `#D8000000`

Answer (score 29):

`85% black` should be `#D8000000`.

Each component (A, R, G, B) can take values from 0-255. `85% of 255 = 216`. `216 in Hex = D8`