# How to apply different colour filters on an image in android?

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I can't figure out how can we apply filters over an image.

In this case I want the image to be darker (black, 40% transparency, layer on top of the image would give me the result I want). However, it will be helpful (in future) if I know how to put a layer over an image of any color (with some transparency) to make it more visually compatible with the other UI elements of the app.

[image: How it looks]

How it looks now.

[image]

How I want it to look on the app (the above image has been edited in Adobe illustrator but the app repeatedly crashes if I use it even though its size is not large)

Also, I suspect there must be a way to do this in android studio without the need of any image editing software.

Correct me if I am wrong ;)

Comment: image have a background and src attributes or use ColorFilter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android black color at 85% opacity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024867/android-black-color-at-85-opacity)

Comment: for opacity see this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17239853/7235539

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what i do ,

```
 imageView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view) ;
 imageView.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0x76ffffff, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
```

color range [0x00000000 -0xffffffff]

If you don't understand the pattern this might help you

> Red - 0xffff0000
>
> green -0xff00ff00
>
> blue - 0xff0000ff
>
> your request average black color 0xff555555

change color codes as you want > [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37323776/5188159)

out put

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Further more :

setColorFilter params : (int color, 
                PorterDuff.Mode mode)

[What does PorterDuff.Mode mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGn3V.png)

Comment: your `here` link is dead

Comment: @Charuka Thanks a lot for taking time to show the output. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:foreground` property of a object to set a color over any object. here i used an `ImageView` to show a image and `android:foreground` to put a filter!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/yourImage"
    android:foreground="#60000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

if you want to do this a layout then use android:background property instead of `android:src` for the source of image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/yourImage"
    android:foreground="#60000000">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha=".5"
            android:src="@drawable/your_naruto_img"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Of course you can adjust the *opacity* accordingly by changing `android:alpha` [0 - 1].

Hope this helps!

Comment: Opacity and color filter is completely different thing!

Answer (score 0):

Generate a 9 patch image using any online tool for the darker image and use that 9 patch in your app. it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/your_drawable">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#66000000"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can set the image to the background of a `RelativeLayout`. Use the `imageview` tag and set background with `transparent` color which you want to set.

Comment: Please don't deface your post by rolling back our improvements.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was

```
ImageView backgroundimage = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.img_view);
backgroundimage.SetColorFilter(Color.Argb(200,0,0,0), PorterDuff.Mode.Overlay);
```

after trying all the above answers.
Hope it helps someone .