# Android Navigation View transparency

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, transparency, navigationview

everyone. Is it possible to make `Navigation View` transparent? 
I have custom layout and try to set 50% transparent background for this layout, `Navigation View` or `Drawer Layout`.

```
android:background="#80000000"
```

but it doesn't  give expected result.

Anybody tried to do this? I would appreciate help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can try:

```
navigationView.getBackground().setAlpha(122);
```

Here you can set the opacity between 0 (fully transparent) to 255 (completely opaque).

you can also use XML value `alpha` that takes double values.

The range is from 0f to 1f (inclusive), 0f being transparent and 1f being opaque:

`android:alpha="0.0"` invisible

`android:alpha="0.5"` see-through

`android:alpha="1.0"` full visible

Comment: JFYI, This makes the content also transparent

Answer (score 4):

If you want transparency with a  color try this..

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
------
// you can even change only one from above to and keep the other one normally 
       navigationView.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x80000000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
       headerView.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x80000000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

**Output:**

[image] [image]

If you need more deatals about which colour codes you can apply check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41355628/5188159)

---

Or if you only want to set **alpha** use `navigationView.getBackground().setAlpha(intNumberTill256);`

p.s Nav headder dark colour is due to it's background colour that i have given in its XML

Comment: Great, +1 ..!  Also as a top user in *Android* tag, can you please answer to this short question? Should I have one `public static void main(){}` method per each either **class** or **file** or **project** ?

Comment: @stack well i would say it like this,First why you want a method like that? Then if you think that should be the way to start fiest method of a class in android..No..In **core Java** programs we need a `main()` method, because while executing the byte code the JVM will search for the `main()` method in the class and start executing there..In the case of **Android**, there is a manifest included in each package. The launchpoint is specified in this manifest.It start the execution of the application from specified class `onCreate()` method, so there is no need of a `main()` method

Comment: @stack read about android life cycle // If you have any doubt post a comment an ask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for

Answer (score 3):

To make navigation view completely transparent, this worked for me.

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: You might also need to add `app:elevation="0dp"`

Answer (score 1):

To make transparent for navigation , please try below code

```
final Window window = getWindow();
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(window,
            "navigationBarColor", window.getNavigationBarColor(), Color.TRANSPARENT);
    animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    animator.setDuration(0);
    animator.start();
```

Comment: `#getNavigationBarColor()` requires API 21