# Unable to make DrawerLayout background to transparent in Samsung s8+

Tags: android, android-layout, drawerlayout

I am using DrawerLayout in my application. I am using NavigationView for the contents of the navigation drawer and setting its background to transparent using below code snip.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start|center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

In Samsung s8+ when I open the drawer it shows a vertical bar at the end. While debugging when I removed transparency from NavigationView what I come to know that Samsung s8+ contain a grey color bar in addition with a background. When I deploy the same code on Red mi 3s it's working fine it just has a background.

Samsung s8+ drawer bg
[image]

Redmi 3s drawer bg
[image]

Samsung s8+ drawer bg transparent
[image]

Redmi 3s drawer bg transparent
[image]

Please help me to remove this vertical bar.

Comment: Could you also try it out on an emulator to understand if Samsung S8+ is behaving differently by adding the grey bar or RedMi behaving differently by removing the bar. Other than that, try setting elevation of the view to 0dp.

Comment: @mtiidla I didn't check on emulator no matter there its working or not. I set elevation to 0dp but it is not working.

Comment: @mtiidla When I set elevation to 0dp that grey border come to left side instead of right side but once I rotate the device again it goes to right and if rotate again it comes to left.

Comment: Okay. One more idea, I suppose you use the DrawerLayout class. It also has its own shadow that it draws. You can maybe make use of DrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(null, Gravity.xyz) and also setDrawerElevation(0)

Comment: @mtiidla Yes, I am using  DrawerLayout and I tried setDrawerShadow() and setDrawerElevation() but that also not working.

Comment: One more thing, try DrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Comment: Sorry, @mtiidla DrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);  also doesn't work :(

Comment: @AmitYadav try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674469/android-navigation-view-transparency

Comment: @WaleedAsim I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674469/android-navigation-view-transparency but that also not worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to run the code right now. However I believe this will work.

```
navigationView.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.SOURCE);
```

Comment: .@Anees navigationView.getBackground() return Drawable and that is not having setBackgroundColor() method. I mean to say that above statement give compilation issue.

Comment: .@Anees, I tried navigationView.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC); but the code snip is not working.

Answer (score -1):

> setDrawerShadow added in version 22.1.0 void setDrawerShadow (Drawable
>   shadowDrawable, 
>                   int gravity) Set a simple drawable used for the left or right shadow. The drawable provided must have a nonzero intrinsic
>   width. For API 21 and above, an elevation will be set on the drawer
>   instead of using the provided shadow drawable.
>
> Note that for better support for both left-to-right and right-to-left
>   layout directions, a drawable for RTL layout (in additional to the one
>   in LTR layout) can be defined with a resource qualifier "ldrtl" for
>   API 17 and above with the gravity START. Alternatively, for API 23 and
>   above, the drawable can auto-mirrored such that the drawable will be
>   mirrored in RTL layout.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout#setDrawerShadow(int,%20int)

Create a color drawable or rectangle shape with **transparent** color `R.drawable.trans`
then use it like this:

```
navigationDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.trans, GravityCompat.END);
```