# Transparent Navigation Drawer with Custom Layout - Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Trying to make Totally transparent `Navigation Drawer` with Custom Design (trying to include
only Custom `layout`).

- Transparent background and Zero `elevation` in `Navigation Drawer`.
- I do not want default `header` or menu `items`, I want to add custom design in other xml `Layout` then include inside

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video Example:[image: Video Example]

If you want, make your `Navigation Drawer` totally `Transparent` then use this. **You can make your custom design in `xml` then `include` inside `NavigationView`.**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawerlayout" <!-- we will use this layout id in java for hide elevation -->
android:orientation="vertical"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" <!-- for transparent -->
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/custom_nav_drawer" />

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

in our `Activity` `java` class for hide `drawer` Shadow/elevation

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
drawerLayout.setDrawerElevation(0f);
```

Answer is complete here.

But if you want `code` of this `DrawerLayout` with `circular Image`
Here is full code.

add `Dependencies`

```
//drawer layout
implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1"
//circle image
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.3.1'
```

**custom_nav_drawer.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/layoutCustomNavDrawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- space  for view just hahah -->
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <!-- buttons in nav -->
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="23dp"
                            android:layout_height="23dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_direction" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/medium"
                            android:text="Bill pay"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />


                    </LinearLayout>


                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="23dp"
                            android:layout_height="23dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_direction" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/medium"
                            android:text="Recharge"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />


                    </LinearLayout>


                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="23dp"
                            android:layout_height="23dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_direction" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/medium"
                            android:text="Complaint Preference"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />


                    </LinearLayout>


                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="23dp"
                            android:layout_height="23dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_direction" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/medium"
                            android:text="Special offer"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />


                    </LinearLayout>


                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="23dp"
                            android:layout_height="23dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_direction" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/medium"
                            android:text="Bill pay"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />


                    </LinearLayout>


                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#FEF9DB"
        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:strokeColor="#FFC50A"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/png_user_photo_blank"
                app:civ_border_color="#3f51b5"
                app:civ_border_width="1dp"
                app:civ_shadow="false"
                app:civ_shadow_color="#3f51b5"
                app:civ_shadow_radius="10dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nav_profile"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium_numbers"
                    android:text="Akshay Jiii"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/semibold"
                    android:text="987654321"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks
Happy Coding:)

Comment: consider gaining reputation by answering questions and resolving problems of other users instead of posting basically trivial answer for own question. besides that: this question was already asked and answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674469/android-navigation-view-transparency), so its duplicate

Comment: @snachmsm , (This is best Example of my question see this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNAe8.png) ). Your linked question making only background transparent but not make `elevation zero`. (self QnA is features of `StackOverflow` for help others). This is not duplicate it covers 3 Major problems to make Modern Navigation drawer.

Comment: still should be answered under already existing question (exacly same "problem") asked earlier, in fact there are plenty of them... some of those might be asked years ago when there were no elevation param, so some answers may be outdated, but still your answer should be placed somewhere there, will gain reputation in time. we don't need yet another link in search engines, we need to ask one clear question and get one (or few alternatives) answers in one topic/link

Comment: Thanks man, this is amazing example and idea.