# How to unBlur square portion of Blurry image on touch android

Tags: android, canvas, android-imageview, ondraw

**What I want to do:**

On mouse hover of Blurry image, it shows unblur same image in square shape like following image. (image is completely blur, on mouse hover unblur image shown in square shape)

**What I have done:**

I set blur image using following code ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355433/how-to-apply-different-colour-filters-on-an-image-in-android/41355628#41355628)) using [PorterDuff.Mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html).  On touch of screen mouse pointer converted into square and image shows unblur.

---

**Edit:**

**Problem:**

Now picture is unblur but i cant find proper blur effect on blurry image and unblur image is also not clear, on touch is not working properly.

**My Code:**

using custom view and following methods i'm able to blur and unblur  image but still there's not completely satisfied with output.

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(mTutorialColor);
        if (mCx >= 0 && mCy >= 0) {
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            // canvas.drawCircle(mCx, mCy, RADIUS, mBackgroundPaint);
            canvas.drawRect(mCx, mCy, mCx + width, mCy + 250, mBackgroundPaint);
        }

    }


private void init() {
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        mBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
        mBackgroundPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        mBackgroundPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    }
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: It is still not clear what is the problem about...

Comment: @Alexandr first of all you can see blur image of cat but it's not much blur so i need to more blur it, so no one can recognize image and when we touch the image it only shows clear image on that touch portion.

Comment: @Alexandr here clear picture is also not much clear and when we touch on screen, touch must be draw rectangle and that restrict to move on x axis. it only moves up and down not left-right.

Comment: did you try my solution?

Comment: hii @Alexandr i'm stuck in other work i'll get back to you after trying this solution, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement it differently.

You need two images (instead of one):

1. Blurred one. Which will be always drawn as background (or in a view underneath). Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2067955/2308720) how to blur the image.
2. Normal one. This one should be drawn on top of blurred one using the square mask. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26031133/2308720).

MORE DETAILS:

It can be done in the same way, how I explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39020368/2308720), but with `Mode.DST_IN` Xfermode instead of `PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR`.

Hope this will help you.